# Is asking questions about TeX jargon on the main site okay?

Tags: support, off-topic

An aspect of learning about the concepts that underlie TeX and LaTeX is learning how to apply terms correctly that are TeX jargon.

Is it on topic to ask about how to apply terms of TeX jargon or about their meaning on the main site?

Here's an example of a question about TeX jargon (using TeX jargon/terminology for naming things in TeX correctly):

> Is the delimiter of a delimited argument to be considered a component of that argument?

Comment: I think you may ask such questions. If I understood well, you would like to ask "What is a glue?", "What is intended for 'baseline'?", or "What is the difference between height and depth of a character?". They are very welcome!

Answer (score 6):

This is definitely on topic for the main site, as jargon deals with (La)TeX.

Comment: Definitely? Well, it's not in the list at [https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) .

Comment: @Cattleya: It *definitely* falls under *etc.*.

Comment: Then "etc" should make a separate item of the list.